# How to check if a string is in an arrayList inside a hashmap

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

So I have a hashmap

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<String> gMap = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>();
```

And when someone creates a group, the group leader is added to the key of the hashmap and then all the users inside the group are added to the arraylist

```
gMap.get(groupLeader).add(user);
```

I'm trying to make it so that only group leaders are allowed to invite players, but if a player is not part of any group and invites another user then a group is automatically created and the player becomes the group leader.

So, normally I would just do this

```
for(ArrayList<String> list : gMap.values()){
    if(list.contains(user)){
        //do something since the player is not part of the list
    }
}
```

But I cannot do that since there could be multiple arrayLists, so even though the user is not part of one arrayList it does not mean that they aren't inside another.

So I'm curios how I would check all the arrayLists and do something only if the user is not part of any of them.

Comment: Get all the `ArrayList` values and check them. Seems like you are already doing that...

Comment: Iterate through your map elements and then search the list of each map entry.

Comment: If you care about performance and scalability, you may want to consider separately keeping track of which group (if any) a player belongs to. Then you get the answer you're looking for in O(1), but you will have to deal with synchronization issues.

Comment: Further to my comment above, you may already need to think about synchronization issues, depending on your use case.

Answer (score 4):

You're actually creating a [Multimap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimap_%28data_structure%29) (a mapping of keys to collections of values) data structure here, and you'll find if you use one directly you won't have to reinvent the wheel as you are now.  [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) defines a very nice [`Multimap interface`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html), including an [`ArrayListMultimap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ArrayListMultimap.html) that stores the data you want, and has a [`containsValue()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ArrayListMultimap.html#containsValue%28java.lang.Object%29) method that cleanly does what you need.  As mentioned by others, contains checks against a list are slow, you could use [`HashMultimap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/HashMultimap.html) to do these contains checks more efficiently if you don't actually care about order, or [`LinkedHashMultimap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/LinkedHashMultimap.html) if you really do.

And if you aren't already using Guava, you're missing out - it provides countless excellent utilities and good practices.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `boolean` value that you only change the value of if a list contains the user - and `break` out of the loop if it does.

```
boolean notInAnyList = true;
for(ArrayList<String> list : gMap.values()){
    if(list.contains(user)){
        notInAnyList = false;
        break; // No point in iterating any further
    }
}

if (notInAnyList) {
    // Handle user not being in any of the lists here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So here is a code sample

```
boolean userIsPartOfGroup = false
for(ArrayList<String> list : gMap.values()){
    if(list.contains(user)){
       userIsPartOfGroup = true;
       break;
    }
}
if(!userIsPartOfGroup){
gMap.add(user).add(new ArrayList(user));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I would use a set instead of a list (Java 7 syntax):

```
Map<String, Set<String> gMap = new HashMap<>();
```

When I understand your goal right, this may be a solution:

```
if (isLeader(groupLeader, gMap)) {
  gMap.get(groupLeader).add(user);
} else if (isMember(groupLeader, gMap)) {
  throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Member " + groupLeader + " is not a leader and must not invite " + user);
} else {
  addNewGroup(groupLeader, gMap).add(user);
}
```

Here are the helper methods:

```
private boolean isLeader(String player, Map<String, Set<String> gMap) {
  return gMap.keys().contains(player);
}

private boolean isMember(String player, Map<String, Set<String> gMap) {
  for (Set<String> members : gMap.values()) {
    if (members.contains(player)) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

private Set<String> addNewGroup(String leader, Map<String, Set<String> gMap) {
  Set<String> players = new HashSet<>();
  gmap.put(leader, players);
  return players;
}
```